# Is there a "Without" pendant to Kotlin.Tests AssertFailsWith?

Tags: kotlin

Using Kotlin.Test to check that a function fails and throws an exception of type IOException is easy:

```
assertFailsWith<IOException> { myFun() }
```

However, i want to also check this call does NOT throw an exception of type `E : IOException`, where `E` is a subtype of `IOException`. Something like

```
assertFailsButWithout<E> { myFun() }
```

How do i do this? Searching for `assertFailsWith` here on SO only yields 5 unrelated results.

---

But why?
I'm testing my network stack implemented in retrofit + okhttp.
The stack throws custom errors of type `E` - which have to subtype IOException, due to some weird restriction of retrofit. I now want to test a case like "A disconnect should fail with an `IOException`, NOT with one of my custom exceptions (e.g. a "MyEmptyResponseError")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test that it fails with IOException, and then assert that the exception is not your custom exception:

```
val thrown = assertFailsWith<IOException> { myFun() }
assertIsNot<MyEmptyResponseError>(thrown)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
assertFailsButWithout<E> { 
    try{
        myFun()
        assertTrue(true)
    }
    catch(ex :E){
        assertTrue(false)
    }
    catch(ex :Exception){
        assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```